# What could cause a previously working point to point to be accessible from only one side?

Tags: routing, troubleshooting, management, point-to-point

I have two sites that are connected using a pair of Motorola Canopy 5.7 Ghz backhaul units.  They have been working for years without a problem but this morning we had a power outage for a few hours and now when we brought everything back online I cannot get the point to point connect to re-establish.  What's odd is Site A (Master) cannot see either Canopy unit at all, but Site B (Slave) can see both Canopy units but cannot see any other device at Site A.

I've checked to make sure there isn't an IP conflict on the network, changed plugs on the switch to make sure it wasn't bad, even ran a new ethernet cable to the switch from the Canopy unit.  Any ideas on what might be going on?

Comment: Perhaps a configuration was not saved to memory before the power outage, causing them to revert to the last save configuration. Rather than look at the cabling have you taken a look at the Canopy's configuration? Are they managed?

Comment: HAL, you're right.  I was looking at the wrong location.  It seems the switch configuration was never saved to startup after a single port change was made, so when it came back online it reverted back to the old configuration as a general port instead of a trunk port.  I wasn't aware the power had gone down at both locations so I didn't think to look at Site B at all, but thanks for the answer.

Comment: Wireless point to point gear can typically operate fine in half duplex mode. i.e. the transmitter or receiver on one side could be damaged,(i.e. a power surge caused by the outage) but you'd still have a usable one way link. Does the management interface on your device tell you about anything odd, and is the configuration as it should be ?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

When a power outage occurs, any unsaved configurations will be dropped by your devices. In this case, your port configuration reverted to an older version.